# Menu bar not same margin with header bar on media screen

Tags: html, css

i'm using a menu bar (as view in osakaairport.com), every thing work fine except i need the menu bar same position with the title in header when viewing in mobile devices. How to re position the logo (OsakaAirport.com) to be view as same column with tittle header?[image: (Refer to attached image for better scenario)]

```
.header{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
   
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #101010;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: left;
    list-style-type: none;

}

.nav-item {
    margin-left: 5rem;
}

.nav-link{
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #475569;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: #482ff7;
}

.nav-logo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #475569;
        
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-menu {
        position: fixed;
        left: -120%;
        top: 5rem;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 80%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        text-color: #000;
        transition: 1.0s;
        box-shadow:;
            }

    .nav-menu.active {
        left: 0;
    }

    .nav-item {
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
    }
```

```
<div id="header-top"></div>
```

```
        <h1>Osaka Kansai International Airport (KIX)</h1>
```

Osaka Kansai International Airport (関西国際空港, Kansai Kokusai Kūkō, colloquially 
known as Kankū (関空)) (IATA: KIX, ICAO: RJBB) is the primary international 
airport in the Greater Osaka Area of Japan and the closest international airport 
to the cities of Osaka, Kyoto, and Kobe. It is located on an artificial island (Kankūjima 
(関空島)) in the middle of Osaka Bay off the Honshu shore, with multiple 
4,000-meter-long runways, it meets the global standards of a truly 24-hour 
operational airport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that when the screen width is <= 768px, `.navbar` should have 0 padding on the left:

```css
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    
}

...

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .navbar {
      padding-left: 0;
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: problem resolved.....appreciated and many thanks...!!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it worked for you :)